# Javascript on demand doesn't work on production server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a strange issue with my scripts on a production server.

I am using this solution to run scripts on demand:

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
 if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
  var fileref=document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
 }
 else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
  var fileref=document.createElement("link")
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
  fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
 }
 if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}
```

it's taken from this page: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

It works smooth in all browsers possible when I run it locally. But on a production server it works only in IE 8 and older...

Here's the actual code I'm calling with this function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#vertical_cssmenu a").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#f22d00"}, 350);
    },function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#e5e5e5" }, 350);
    }); 
    $("#vertical_cssmenu a").click(function() {
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #text_content > *';
        $('#text_content').fadeOut(500,loadContent);
        $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-4);
        function loadContent() {
            $('#text_content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent());
        }
        function showNewContent() {
            $('#text_content').fadeIn(1000);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Please help me out guys :)

EDIT: here's the code for main javascript on page:

```
// dynamiczne ladowanie CSS i JS
 function ensureUploadScriptIsLoaded() {
   if (self.uploadScript) { // Already exists
     return;
   }
   var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
   script = document.createElement('script');
   script.id = 'uploadScript';
   script.type = 'text/javascript';
   script.src = "js/vertical.js";
   head.appendChild(script);
 }


// fullscreen BG

$(window).load(function ()
{
    var theWindow = $(window),
        $bg = $("#bg"),
        aspectRatio = $bg.width() / $bg.height();

    function resizeBg()
    {
        if ((theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio)
        {
            $bg.removeClass()
                .addClass('bgheight');
        }
        else
        {
            $bg.removeClass()
                .addClass('bgwidth');
        }
    }
    theWindow.resize(function ()
    {
        resizeBg();
    }).trigger("resize");
});
// RSS
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#divRss').FeedEk(
    {
        FeedUrl: 'http://someurl.here',
        MaxCount: 5,
        ShowDesc: true,
        ShowPubDate: true
    })
    // baner    
    $('#acc-holder').easyAccordion(
    {
        autoStart: true,
        slideInterval: 5000,
        slideNum: false
    });
    // menu animacja
    $("#horizontal_cssmenu a").hover(function ()
    {
        $(this).stop().animate(
        {
            backgroundColor: "#f22d00"
        }, 750);
    }, function ()
    {
        $(this).stop().animate(
        {
            backgroundColor: "#790079"
        }, 350);
    });
    // ladowanie 
    $("#horizontal_cssmenu a").click(function ()
    {
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#contentsth').fadeOut('150', loadContent);
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0, $(this).attr('href').length - 4);

        function loadContent()
        {
            $('#contentsth').load(toLoad, showNewContent);
        }

        function showNewContent()
        {
            $('#contentsth').fadeIn(1000, ensureUploadScriptIsLoaded);
        }
        return false;
    });
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    var href = $('#horizontal_cssmenu a').each(function ()
    {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (hash == href.substr(0, href.length - 4))
        {
            var toLoad = hash + '.htm';
            $('#contentsth').load(toLoad)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe you are vioating the same-origin-policy of the web browser?

Comment: *"it works only in IE 8 and older..."* Are you saying it doesn't work in IE7? or it doesn't work in chrome firefox safari and opera.

Comment: Agreed, checkout the javascript console in any of the modern browsers for any errors

Comment: @Philipp That shouldn't matter for script and css includes.

Comment: You are calling `showNewContent` too soon, remove the `()`

Comment: It works in IE6, IE7 and IE8. All the modern browsers refuse to load script.

Im calling the script from the "js/" directory on same domain so it shouldn't freak out, also jquery is stored in the js dir, not on google. So there arn't any scripts that are loaded from different domain :/

Comment: How is `loadjscssfile` actually called? IS the second code block loaded from the function?

Comment: edit: used http://jsbeautifier.org/ to make "the code for main javascript on page" easier to read

Comment: it's called on the end of another function used to load contents from the main menu, the second part of code is for the sub menus in the loaded content.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#text_content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent());
```

needs to be

```
$('#text_content').load(toLoad, '', showNewContent);
```

and since you are not sending up data, you can just do

```
$('#text_content').load(toLoad, showNewContent);
```

Comment: changes applied... and the problem remains :/

Comment: okey guys, thanks for help I managed to debug it... Turned out that the aforementioned scripts where also included in the head part of loaded documents and apparently those scripts blocked the proper script execution :)

Comment: ok after some serious testing there is a problem again...
it doesn't work on safari for some reason.

Can any one suggest a better, more cross-browser way to handle the script on demand? ahh and additionaly old IE dont work now either, seems like they actually load scripts from loaded documents trough ajax (LOL?)